# Punif and Quinf Functions in R

Tags: r, math

I have a question:

If X is a random variable in a density function which is uniform between -2 and 3.

I want to find these two questions:

1. What is the upper quartile of X?
2. What is the 44% quantile of X?

Now the things I have tried are below:

```
z <- 1 - punif(0.75, min = -2, max = 3, lower.tail = TRUE)
answer: 0.45

y <- qunif(0.44, min = -2, max = 3, lower.tail = TRUE)
answer: 0.2
```

First is this even the right way to go about it.
Second, I understand that Punif finds the accumulate probability of X. What does qunif find, and what does the result tell me about X and the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If is you have a random variable `x` with uniform distribution from `a` to `b`

```
X ~ U(a,b)
```

Then `punif(x, a, b)` is the probability that `U <= x`

And `qunif(x, a, b)` finds the value `y` such that `Pr(U <= y)=x`

You can visualize these plots with

```
curve(punif(x, -2, 3), from=-2, to=3, main="punif")
curve(qunif(x, -2, 3), from=0, to=1, main="qunif")
```

[image]

Note how `punif` expects a value anywhere between `a` and `b` but `qunif` expects a probability so it must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Okay, So was what I was doing correct? As in to answer those questions?

Comment: Well, do the values you were trying to calculate match the description of the functions I provided? This isn't a place to have someone "check your work" or "grade your homework." Feel free to ask specific programming questions, but if you have basic statistical questions, then you might consider asking those at [stats.se] instead.